# php / composer not loading interface

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I've banged my head against the wall for 3/4 of a day now and just can't see the error of my ways.

I'm creating (or trying to!) a simple package that consists of a couple of classes and 1 interface.  This is in github at https://github.com/dnorth98/victoropsnotifier

Basically though, there's the following directory structure:

```
victoropsnotifer
    src
        Signiant
            VictorOpsNotifier
                Transport.php
                VictorOpsNotifier.php
```

Transport is very simple:

```
<?php
    namespace Signiant\VictorOpsNotifer;
     interface Transport
     {
          // must POST the $message to the VictorOps REST endpoint
          public function send(Messages\Message $message);
     }
```

and the beginning of VictorOpsNotifier is

```
<?php
    namespace Signiant\VictorOpsNotifer;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    class VictorOpsNotifer implements Transport
    {
         protected $endpoint_url;
         :
         :
```

The problem comes when I try to instantiate a new object using

```
<?php
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Signiant\VictorOpsNotifier\Messages\CustomMessage;
    use Signiant\VictorOpsNotifier\VictorOpsNotifier;

    $voConfig = ['routing_key' => 'test',
                 'endpoint_url' => 'https://goo'];

    $voHandle = new VictorOpsNotifier($voConfig);
```

I get back

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Signiant\VictorOpsNotifer\Transport' not found in /tmp/djn/tests/vendor/signiant/
victoropsnotifier/src/Signiant/VictorOpsNotifier/VictorOpsNotifier.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/djn/tests/test.php:0
PHP   2. spl_autoload_call() /tmp/djn/tests/test.php:12
PHP   3. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /tmp/djn/tests/test.php:0
PHP   4. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /tmp/djn/tests/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:301
PHP   5. include() /tmp/djn/tests/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:412
```

What on EARTH am I missing?  Composer is finding the package ok from my github repo and everying is in the vendor folder and looks ok.  It looks like the namespaces match...so for some reason, it's just not loading the Transport.php file containing the interface.

Comment: Are you using PSR-0 by composer.json? There's a typo like Etki already said, if it didn't fix you should see your PSR-0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be just a typo:

```
namespace Signiant\VictorOpsNotifer;
                                 ^ no `i` in here
```

but

```
use Signiant\VictorOpsNotifier\VictorOpsNotifier;
                           ^ but here it is
```

same thing with the class name.

Also, you're declaring namespace `Signiant` as `src/`, but it's really `src/Signiant`

By the way, there's no need to declare this package as psr-0, better to use psr-4 insetad. Not a big deal, just for conformity.

P.S. The strange thing it was complaining about interface, while it shouldn't have to until it hit the class, and it certainly must not hit the class while there was a typo.

P.P.S You can easily avoid those typo errors by using a proper IDE, PHPStorm, for example. It would highlight name of the class as missing as long as there wre typos (and i don't even start talking about autocompletion).

Comment: Unreal.  It was in fact just a typo!  Thanks VERY much guys.  I only do PHP every now and then so my IDE is "vi" :)  But I will look into something like PHPStorm.

Thanks again!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

```
class VictorOpsNotifer implements \Signiant\VictorOpsNotifer\Transport{}
```

try add namespace before your interface.

Comment: can do just VictorOpsNotifer\Transport because namespace all already declared on top